# Duplicate nodes in drupal-views - but not in preview

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

i have a view that only lists those nodes that have a certain workflow-status (published). In the preview everything works as expected. But when viewing the site, i get duplicate nodes. Anyone an idea how to solve this problem or where it originates?

Greatings

Comment: Are you using taxonomy terms in the view filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking Distinct: Yes under the view options. This generally solves the issue.

If Taxonomy is being used as a filter, there should be an option for it too thats says 'Reduce duplicate results' or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit View
2. Under the "Basic Settings" section, enable the "Distinct" option.

Hope that helps!